# Android custom properties not loaded on clean install

Tags: java, android

I am developing an android app that reads some properties from a file that I created containing just a few properties. When the `onCreate()` method is called from the MainActivity, the properties are loaded and some global variables are set, using those properties obtained from the file. 
The problem is that when the app starts after a clean install, those properties are ignored, and no values are set. If I exit the app, and run it again, all the values are set correctly. 
I suspect that the `onCreate()` method runs and requests the properties faster than the app has time to set them. On the second launch, those properties are there from the previous run. 
The app uses a map, and the same problem happens afte a clean install: no location is shown, but after restarting the app (no uninstall) the map is displayed correctly, as are the properties.

The code looks something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    requestPermissions();
    initializeMap();
    loadConfigurations();
    addListenersToButtons();
    PropertyManager.createPropertyFileIfNotPresent();
    PropertyManager.readProperties();
}
```

And the PropertyManager methods:

```
public static void createPropertyFileIfNotPresent() {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + PROPERTY_PATH);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        OutputStream output = null;
        try {
            final String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + PROPERTY_PATH;
            output = new FileOutputStream(path);
            prop.setProperty("property1", "1234");
            prop.setProperty("property2", "5678");
            prop.setProperty("property3", "60");
            prop.store(output, null);
        } catch (IOException io) {
            io.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            closeStream(output);
        }
    }
}

public static void readProperties() {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream input = null;

    try {
        final String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + PROPERTY_PATH;
        input = new FileInputStream(path);
        prop.load(input);

        GlobalData.getInstance().property1 = prop.getProperty("property1");
        GlobalData.getInstance().property2 = prop.getProperty("property2");
        GlobalData.getInstance().property3 = prop.getProperty("property3");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        closeStream(input);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on how to ensure that all the properties are set after a clean install, without using a loading page on startup?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You will need to add the code related to the ProperyManager for people to help you with this. On a side note, I suggest you use SharedPreferences instead. The methods provide a default return value if the property doesn't exist yet. You can even set a property to flag if it is the first time the app is run.

Comment: PropertyManager code added, however, this behaviour doesn't only affect properties, but the map location as well. If the problem was in the way the properties were read, why does this only happen after a clean install? The problem with sharedpreferences is that they are reset when app is uninstalled or factory reset. I need these properties ready on the first load after a new installation. Thanks again

Comment: have you tried using AsyncTask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was causing the issue.
What I suspected in the original post, turned out to be true. - "I suspect that the onCreate() method runs and requests the properties faster than the app has time to set them."

What I did to workaround the issue was to override the following method, and only create the map and run the code that needed the properties, once it was invoked:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) { 
// do the work that needs the permissions here
}
```

Thanks for your suggestions